# Android: How to change my action bar background color

Tags: android

I used Android Studio to create a project with activity that uses ListView and a navigation drawer template, I'm targeting API 14+ and I'm testing on Galaxy Note 3 Kitkat - the result of the code below is "Nothing" the action bar color is black (very dark grey) not blue as I intend.

in build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'}
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

in Styles.xml (where I have AppTheme)

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/drawer_list_selector</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/blue_action_bar_color</item>
</style>
```

in blue_action_bar_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/action_bar"/>
</shape>
```

in colors.xml

```
<color name="action_bar">#3b5b98</color>
```

**So what am I missing here?**

**EDIT1:**

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

**EDIT2:**

I can't use

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
```

as my application crash with error message:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Comment: are you using toolbar as action bar?

Comment: [https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Comment: @JayShah Sorry I don't understand your question, I've not worked on UI before, so I don't know what is toolbar. I created the UI from a template provided by Android Studio, also please see the edit of the action bar used libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing is you're extending `ActionBarActivity` which comes with `AppCompat` package and implementing  `Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar` style to it. It is obvious you'll be getting that error. 
So do one thing just update your style a little as follow:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColorActionBar</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColorActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Also, `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated in latest appcompat update i.e. `22.1.1` . So better use `AppCompatActivity`instead.

Comment: Again thank you, and for future searchers, I updated (Android Support Library to v22.1.1) via SDK Manager and just replaced ActionBarActivity with AppCompatActivity and in build.gradle file I set (compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1').

Comment: Thanks ... Is your solution using (colorPrimaryDark - colorPrimary) supported on devices running API less than 21? check Xcihnegn: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010744/android-how-to-change-my-action-bar-background-color/30011422#comment48141283_30010775

Comment: Of course. You can test in below versions, but make sure it's not below 9.  for more query, you can reach me [in this room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era)

Comment: For sure I will, because now after I used AppCompatActivity the application crashes, I'm trying to find the crash error message.

Answer (score 0):

Actually just change:

```
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"  
                 parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
   <item name="android:background">@drawable/blue_action_bar_color</item>
</style>
```

to be:

```
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
                 parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
   <item name="android:background">@drawable/blue_action_bar_color</item>
</style>
```